# Empty jQuery UI Tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

How can I empty (remove all tabs) a jQuery UI Tabs?

*EDIT: I'm not trying to remove the tab functionality, but to empty all tabs to add new ones.*

I'm trying with:

```
for (var i = $('#content').tabs('length') - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    $('#content').tabs('remove', i);
}
```

But tabs('length') always returns 0, even if there are some tabs added to the control.

BTW, I'm initializing it empty

```
$('#content').tabs();
```

and adding tabs dynamically afterwards

```
$('#content').tabs( 'add' , '' , data[i].nombre);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try adding tabs with non empty url?

```
$('#content').tabs( 'add' , 'non empty url' , data[i].nombre);
```

Copied from official documentation (http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#method-add)

```
.tabs( 'add' , url , label , [index] )
```

Add a new tab. The second argument is either a URL consisting of a fragment identifier only to create an in-page tab or a full url (relative or absolute, no cross-domain support) to turn the new tab into an Ajax (remote) tab. The third is the zero-based position where to insert the new tab. Optional, by default a new tab is appended at the end.

Answer (score 6):

I was having trouble iterating through the tabs and removing them all like you do in your question. My solution was to remove the 0th tab a number of times equal to the value returned by the "length" method of the tabs object:

```
var tab_count = $('#tabs').tabs('length');
for (i=0; i<tab_count; i++){
    $('#tabs').tabs( "remove" , 0 )
}
```

Comment: Sorry, what ? `Error: no such method 'length' for tabs widget instance` ([indeed](https://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/))

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue. In order remove tabs from a previous request before loading new tabs, I took these steps:

1. removed the tabs (#tabs ul li),
2. removed tab content (#tabs div) and
3. refreshed the tabs.

Here is the code I used. Works for me. Hope it works for you.

```
$('div#tabs ul li').remove();
$('div#tabs div').remove();
$("div#tabs").tabs("refresh");
```

The other solutions I found posted on the web did not work for me.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to just unbind the tabs from the selector.

```
$('#content').unbind();
```

EDIT:

Straight from jQuery Documentation

```
.tabs( 'destroy' );
```

Remove the tabs functionality completely. This will return the element back to its pre-init state.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I'm not trying to clear the tab functionality but to remove current tabs to add new ones.